# EntityGraph - You must define a fetch group manager at descriptor in order to set a fetch group on the query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entitygraph

I would like use  Entity Graphs in EclipseLink and GlassFish.

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
         @NamedQuery(name = "invoice.all", query = "SELECT i FROM Invoice i")})


    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.invoice",
                attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("invoiceNum")})

    @Table(name = "INVOICE")
    public class Invoice implements Serializable {
            private int id;
            private String bizonylatSzam;
            ...
        }

EntityManager em = getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
EntityGraph eg = em.createEntityGraph("graph.invoice");
List<Invoice> invoiceList =  em.createNamedQuery("invoice.all").setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", eg).getResultList();
```

If I use `javax.persistence.loadgraph` graph everything OK, but if i  use `javax.persistence.fetchgraph` I have an exception:

org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: You must define a fetch group manager at descriptor (Invoice) in order to set a fetch group on the query (invoice.all)

In EclipseLink webpage write:

> ...  using Weaving technologi..
>
> Weaving and Java EE Application Servers
>
> The default EclipseLink weaving behavior applies in any Java EE
>   JPA-compliant application server using the EclipseLink JPA persistence
>   provider. To change this behavior, modify your persistence.xml file
>   (for your JPA entities or POJO classes) to use EclipseLink JPA
>   properties, EclipseLink JPA annotations, or both.

I dont understand what is the problem. :(