# org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.FetchGroupTracker using EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, jpa-2.2

I have the following design:

[image]

One sports game has two scores (one per team) and each score has multiple player stats, one per jersey number. Both relationships are mapped as `Map`. This is just multi-level aggregation.

`Game` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Games\"")
@NamedQuery(name = Game.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT ga FROM Game ga")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Game.FETCH_SCORES, attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("scores")})
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Game.FETCH_SCORES_AND_PLAYER_STATS,
                  attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode(value = "scores", subgraph = Score.FETCH_PLAYER_STATS)},
                  subgraphs = {@NamedSubgraph(name = Score.FETCH_PLAYER_STATS, attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("playerStats"))}
)
public class Game implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Game.findAll";
    public static final String FETCH_SCORES = "Game.fetchScores";
    public static final String FETCH_SCORES_AND_PLAYER_STATS = "Game.fetchScoresAndPlayerStats";

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "scheduled_tipoff")
    private LocalDateTime scheduledTipoff;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    // @MapKey(name = "home")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "is_home", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Map<Boolean, Score> scores;

    ...
}
```

`Score` entity (PK is "home or away of a game", so a `Boolean home` in the PK is enough):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Scores\"")
@IdClass(ScoreId.class)
public class Score implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FETCH_PLAYER_STATS = "Score.fetchPlayerStats";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    private Integer gameId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "is_home")
    private Boolean home;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "roster_id")
    private Integer rosterId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "final_score")
    private Integer finalScore;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Game game;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "score")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "jersey_nbr")
    private Map<Integer, PlayerStat> playerStats;

    ...
}
```

`ScoreId` PK class:

```
public class ScoreId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer game;

    private Boolean home;

    ...
}
```

`PlayerStat` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"PlayerStats\"")
@IdClass(PlayerStatId.class)
public class PlayerStat implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    private Integer gameId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "is_home")
    private Boolean home;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private Integer playerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "jersey_nbr", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer jerseyNbr;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "game_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "is_home", referencedColumnName = "is_home", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Score score;
    
    ...
}
```

`PlayerStatId`:

```
public class PlayerStatId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer gameId;

    private Boolean home;

    private Integer playerId;

    ...
}
```

The following query works:

```
// fetch only scores: OK
games = gameService.findByNamedQuery( Game.FIND_BY_GROUP, Game.FETCH_SCORES, with( "roundId", group.getRoundId() ).and( "groupCode", group.getCode() ).map() );
```

Taking it one level further to fetch player stats attached to each score:

```
// fetch player stats: not OK
games = gameService.findByNamedQuery( Game.FIND_BY_GROUP, Game.FETCH_SCORES_AND_PLAYER_STATS, with( "roundId", group.getRoundId() ).and( "groupCode", group.getCode() ).map() );
```

...EclipseLink fails with:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.FetchGroupTracker
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:493)
    at net.bbstatstest.i303.GameService.findAllWithScores(GameService.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInCallerTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:203)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:55)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:86)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorSupports.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorSupports.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.delegateInterception(EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:252)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.FetchGroupTracker
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager.getObjectFetchGroup(FetchGroupManager.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.load(ObjectBuilder.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.load(AbstractSession.java:5335)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3356)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.buildDelegate(IndirectMap.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.getDelegate(IndirectMap.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.size(IndirectMap.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.MapContainerPolicy.sizeFor(MapContainerPolicy.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.TransparentIndirectionPolicy.instantiateObject(TransparentIndirectionPolicy.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.instantiateAttribute(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.load(CollectionMapping.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.load(ObjectBuilder.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.load(AbstractSession.java:5335)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.load(AbstractSession.java:5327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2983)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    ... 179 more
```

**QUESTION**:

What's wrong? There must be something going wrong with `subgraph = Score.FETCH_PLAYER_STATS`.

Is this a bug in EclipseLink? Mappings wrong? Query + graph wrong?

EclipseLink version is 2.7.7, see stacktrace.

PS: This works in Hibernate BTW.

Comment: Odd, as error comes from ((FetchGroupTracker)domainObject)._persistence_getFetchGroup(); which I don't see how it could return something other than a FetchGroupTracker instance.Try the latest (hail marry type response), but debugging would be required - can you get the woven classes and put a break point in Score's _persistence_getFetchGroup() to see where it is coming from - I suspect a bug but can't tell without stepping through it myself.

Comment: Hmmm. I believe I could possibly get the woven classes. I'm not a great debugger user. Eclipse BTW. Hmm. How do I get the woven classes?

Comment: I tried the latest EclipseLink version and it still throws the same exception. I will try to provide compile a more minimum example...

Comment: Last I tried it, I just used static weaving, decompiled the .class file, and just use that in debugging as the 'source'. A break point in EclipseLink classes though might mean you don't need it, as you can inspect the byte code for your model classes without the woven java files.

Comment: I added a test scenario here: https://github.com/kawoolutions/primefaces-test/tree/master/src/main/java/org/eclipselink/test/ccemapfetchgrouptracker However, the I was only able to get EclipseLink to run with **static weaving** (Maven plugin, see pom.xml). The exception doesn't occurr in this sample test case. I suspect it has something to do with dynamic weaving? Do you happen to have a link to a working EclipseLink test project, e.g. on Github?? This error is very annoying...

Comment: I seem to have gotton it to go with dynamic weaving now. I get the following exception: `Exception Description: You must define a fetch group manager at descriptor (org.eclipselink.test.ccemapfetchgrouptracker.entity.Game) in order to set a fetch group on the query (Game.findAll)
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Game.findAll" referenceClass=Game sql="SELECT ID, ATTENDANCE, official_nbr, scheduled_tipoff FROM "Games"")`. Much like unanswered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338358/entitygraph-you-must-define-a-fetch-group-manager-at-descriptor-in-order-to-se

Comment: So static weaving 'works'? IMO that is the preferred solution. It certainly indicates that weaving is a problem in your environment though, and seems related to the "You must define a fetch group manager at descriptor" error message. Your 1:1 relationships are marked eager, but I'm guessing are eager even if you marked them as lazy as lazy requires weaving. Any luck debugging with a breakpoint where you get that ClassCastException? Your debugger might let you just break when it is encountered and you can see the 'domainObject' in question.

Comment: Looks like this is already an issue in EclipseLink, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495892

It boils down to EclipseLink being unable to handle a `Map` type using entity **sub graphs**.

When using `@MapKey`, the CCE is `Hashtable` to `FetchgroupTracker`, if you use `@MapKeyColumn` the CCE is `IndirectMap` to `FetchGroupTracker`.

Comment: Same issue from 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746308/jpa-entitygraph-and-map